# How to generate iterations of list object in R

Tags: r

I'd like to generate set of list object.
To start, I have a 2*2 matrix from which I should get a list of output.
The list contains: a projection matrix, an asymptotic dynamic, a transient dynamic and a matrix of elasticity: hence 4 objects. I can have all of them from the function `projection`.

My difficulty is that:
In task 1, I'd like to vary one of the elements (the third called `gamma`) of the starting matrix and then get a list of as many output as possible.
What I did shows only the first element of the list for each iteration.

```
#Creating function projection matrix
projection<- function(sigma1,sigma2,gama,phi){
 A <- matrix(c(sigma1*(1-gama),phi,sigma1*gama, sigma2), 
              byrow = T, ncol = 2)
 if(sigma1>1|sigma1<0){stop("sigma1 must be bounded in 0 and 1")}
 if(gama>1|gama<0){stop("gama must be bounded in 0 and 1")}
 if(phi<0){stop("phi must be greater or equal to 0")}
library(popbio)
        e.a <- eigen.analysis(A) 
 as <- e.a$lambda1
        tr <- -log(as)
 Dynamic <- list(projection.matrix = A, assymtotic.dynamic=as,
                 transient.dynamic=tr, Elasticity=e.a$elasticities)
 return(Dynamic)
}

#Try with B
B <- projection(0.5,0.9,0.1,1.5)

#Task 1
Task1 <- function(Gama){
        n <- length(as.vector(Gama))
        g <- list()
        for (i in 1:n){g[i]<-projection(sigma1 = 0.5,sigma2 =  0.9,
                                        gama = Gama[i],phi = 1.5)}
    return(g)
} 
G <- seq(from=0, to=1, by= 0.1)
Task1(G)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community: This was a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly easy fix. Instead of using `[<-` for the assignment of the indexed projection-object use instead the `[[<-` function and don't forget to assign the result to an object name so you can inspect and use it. Otherwise there will only be material printed at the console but the result will be in the (temporary) environment of the function which will get garbage-collected.

```
Task1 <- function(Gama){
    n <- length(as.vector(Gama))
    g <- list()
    for (i in 1:n){g[[i]]<-projection(sigma1 = 0.5,sigma2 =  0.9,
                                    gama = Gama[i],phi = 1.5)}
    return(g)
} 
G <- seq(from=0, to=1, by= 0.1)
resG <- Task1(G)

resG[1]
#--- result is a list of list.
[[1]]
[[1]]$projection.matrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5  1.5
[2,]  0.0  0.9

[[1]]$assymtotic.dynamic
[1] 0.9

[[1]]$transient.dynamic
[1] 0.1053605

[[1]]$Elasticity
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
```

Comment: Now i want to record all the asymptotic.dynamic values in a vector. Is there a method to avoid writing c(resG[[1]]$asymtotic.dynamic, resG[[2]]$asymtotic.dynamic,...) ? So that i can have the vector of asymtotic.dynamic, the one of transient.dynamic and the last value of the elasticity matrix.

Comment: `sapply(resG, "[[", "assymtotic.dynamic")` returns `[1] 0.900000 1.029436 1.110977 1.173293 1.224500 1.268271 1.306637 1.340858 1.371780 1.400000 1.425961`

Comment: It's working as well. Now i'm trying to get the last element of elasticity. I mean the [2,2] element of the matrix. But i'm not getting.

Comment: I've got the result doing the following ```v <- sapply(resG, "[[", 'Elasticity') ; v1 <- v[4,]```. output ```1.0000000 0.7146290 0.6247174 0.5759011 0.5440368 0.5211475 0.5037036 0.4898633 0.4785565 0.4691120 0.4610840```

Comment: If you used `lapply` (or `sapply` with SIMPLIFY=FALSE), you would use either `[2,2]` or `[4]`. Using `sapply` will stack all its results on top of each other if they are all the same length. Not a good extraction procedure for matrices, since they loose their dim-attribute. You might want to read up on the SO mechanism for responding to answered questions at  https://stackoverflow.com/tour